# Flickr API oAuth POST request using Guzzle 6 invalid signature

Tags: php, oauth, flickr

I am successfully able to perform the handshake and access my Flickr account using GET requests, but when I try to POST, specifically the method flickr.favorites.add I get a oauth_signature error (signature invalid). I am clearly not formulating the request properly.

```
$guzzle = $client->request('POST', API_ENDPOINT ['form_params'=>$mergedRequestParams]);
```

I've tried dropping the auth params into a header authorization array, but maybe I had the syntax wrong? Flickr API docs haven't been much help.

I'm getting ready to ditch my efforts for the Guzzle oAuth1 subscriber, but I thought it would be a cool learning experience. Actually it's been mostly frustrating given the Flickr API docs.